# Using Excel as data source for automation across multiple systems

Tags: ruby, selenium, selenium-webdriver, browser-automation, win32ole

I'm trying to automate a web application where I've to load data from mainframe text files to the GUI.

***Scenario***

There will be one row in text file for each entry. We may have multiple rows in the file for a single customer.

for e.g. one customer having two accounts stored in two separate rows as below:

CUST_1  0000001

CUST_1  0000002

***WorkFlow***

Step 1: Create Customer

Step 2: Add Accounts

Now my current logic was to create a customer and add account to it as present in the record. But in case of multiple entries for the same customer, I want to open the customer and then add account to it.

**Current Approach**

I've planned to capture the unique identifier for the customer and add it to an excel sheet. So before adding a customer, the code will check if that customer is present in the sheet.

***Problem Statement***

This script will be executed across 40 systems. So 40 different systems will try to access the same excel file. Can this create some problem as 40 users will try to read/write the same excel sheet at the same time.

Any other approach is more than welcomed :)

Comment: Can you install any SQL server?

Comment: no, I am on client machines so don't have much access.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are likely going to have issues. You can have multiple scripts read from an Excel sheet but when you add writing to Excel, two scripts cannot write to Excel at the same time.

There are several options.

1. ThomasSevestre is on the right track, I think. I would suggest that you set up a centralized database that all the 40 systems can access and have the script write to the db. I think that is the best solution. It doesn't have to be SQL Server, it could be MySQL or any other db that you can set up locally.
2. You can write a local log (text, CSV, etc.) and then when the script is done, you can merge all the different logs together. It's a little more of a manual process but it shouldn't be that bad as long as you write a script to do the merging. If you can't or don't want to deal with a database, this is probably your best option.
3. Another solution is to retry the write to Excel. As long as you have some gaps between the potential write, it might be alright. I don't think I would recommend this approach but you could try it and see how it goes. If your script runs very quickly, you might get a lot of delays as the scripts wait for each other to finish writing.

Comment: For Solution 1, I agree setting up the database is the best solution and that is what I'm going to request to the clients. For Solution 2, Reading the log file and looking for a particular line might me a time consuming task. Solution 3, is something that is only going to increase execution time for me (which is the least thing I want in the suite).

Comment: If this answered your question, please accept the answer so the question isn't left unanswered.